# Quando tento fazer um canvas não da erro mas tambem nao faz nada

Tags: canvas

Gostava de saber o que estou a fazer de errado aqui...

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function draw() {
    if (!Modernizr.canvas) return; {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
      ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 100);
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", draw, false);
  }
</script>

<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Seu navegador suporta canvas?

Answer (score 1):

Alguns erros:

- nesse ficheiro não vejo o script do `Modernizr`
- o `.addEventListener` que vai chamar a tua função está dentro da própria função, ou seja, nunca será chamado
- corrige a sintaxe de `if/else`, não vejo nenhum else, só um bloco depois do *end statement* a seguir ao `return`.
- talvez queiras usar o `DOMContentLoaded`, ele é chamado antes do `load`

Testa assim:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 100);
  }
  window.addEventListener("load", draw, false);
</script>

<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando vou trabalhar com Canvas, não gosto de escrever a tag direto no arquivo HTML, crio uma função pra ficar responsável por isso, até ajuda pra caso eu vá usar o mesmo arquivo JS em outro documento, não vou precisar reescrever a tag, já que a própria função cria, e lança no corpo do documento, Espero que ajude

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {

    var canvas, ctx, lar = alt = 300;

    function writeCanvas() {
      canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width  = lar;
      canvas.height = alt;
      canvas.innerHTML = "Elemento não suportado";

      document.body.appendChild(canvas);

      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      drawRect('red', 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    };

    function drawRect (color, x0, y0, x1, y1) {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(x0, y0, x1, y1);
    };




    writeCanvas();
  } ());
</script>
```